# If $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $v = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$, can we have $|a_1| > 3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

Question: Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a unit vector. If $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $v = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$, can we have $|a_1| > 3$?

What I think:

Since the norm of $v$ is one, then

$\sqrt{v\cdot v} = 1$

$(a_1v_1)^2 + (a_2v_2)^2 + (a_3v_3)^2 = 1^2$

Since $3^2 = 9 $ and $v_1 \cdot v_1 = 1^2$ (since each vector's norm in an orthonormal basis is 1), then $(a_1v_1) \geq 9$. Since $(a_2v_2)^2 + (a_3v_3)^2 > 0,$ then $(a_1v_1)^2 + (a_2v_2)^2 + (a_3v_3)^2 > 1$. Hence, $|a_1| < 3.$

I'm pretty sure my assumption of $(a_1v_1) \geq 9$ is wrong but I don't know how else to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Isn't $v=4v_1$ a trivial example with $|a_1|=4>3$? Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume he missed $|v| = 1$

Comment: @Gono: In context, you're definitely right, and it makes sense. I've added it to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The norm squared $v\cdot v$ of $v = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$ is $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2$ because $[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ is orthonormal. Clearly $|a_1|>3$ would contradict that norm-squared being $1$ (it would have to be${}>9$ since squares are${}\geq0$).